# How to check if a file with a certain extension exists using a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to check whether exists files with a certain extension in a makefile, however this piece of code does not work:

```
ejecutar: $(OUTPUT) clean
    ifeq (,$(wildcard *.dat))
        ./$(OUTPUT) < $(OUTPUT).dat >$(OUTPUT).txt
    else
    ./$(OUTPUT) < $(OUTPUT).dat >$(OUTPUT).txt
```

The error is said to be in the ifeq line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stuff in the recipe should be shell script, not Makefile syntax.  Anything that Make interprets gets expanded as the Makefile is being read, where you typically want your recipe to examine things as they are when that specific recipe is executed. (This is a common beginner FAQ.)

Checking whether a wildcard matches any files in shell script is surprisingly unobvious, too.

```
ejecutar: $(OUTPUT) clean
    set -- *.dat \
    ; if [ -e "$$1" ]; then \
        ./$< < $<.dat >$<.txt; \
    else \
        ./$< < $<.dat >$<.txt; \
    fi
```

It's also weird that your `then` and `else` cases are identical, but I'm not judging.

Comment: You can use GNU make functions in recipes, just not directives like `ifeq` etc.  GNU make's `wildcard` function is simpler to use in this situation than the shell because it expands to the empty string if nothing matches, rather than the glob expression.  So, `if [ -n '$(wildcard *.dat)' ]; then ...` will be good enough.

Comment: Not a bad workaround per se, but I wanted to hit two birds with one stone.  That would fail if one of the files contains a literal single quote, though.

Comment: True.  You could certainly fix that if you were worried... fixing quotes is actually simpler in make functions because it doesn't care about them.  Just `$(subst ','"'"',$(...))` or similar will work.